# Interpreting mod_fcgid in log file

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-fcgid

I am getting a 500 error occasionally, and it is becoming more frequent. Looking in the apache error log, I find the following.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to discovering the cause of the problem?

```
[Mon Apr 14 19:17:26 2014] [info] mod_fcgid: server mysite.com:/var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(2617) started
[Mon Apr 14 19:17:29 2014] [info] mod_fcgid: server mysite.com:/var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(2620) started
[Mon Apr 14 19:17:44 2014] [info] mod_fcgid: server mysite.com:/var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(2628) started
[Mon Apr 14 19:17:44 2014] [info] mod_fcgid: server mysite.com:/var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(2629) started
[Mon Apr 14 19:18:08 2014] [debug] fcgid_pm_main.c(357): mod_fcgid: gracefully terminated 2 processes
[Mon Apr 14 19:18:14 2014] [info] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(2620) exit(lifetime expired), terminated by calling exit(), return code: 0
[Mon Apr 14 19:18:14 2014] [info] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(2617) exit(lifetime expired), terminated by calling exit(), return code: 0
[Mon Apr 14 19:18:20 2014] [debug] fcgid_pm_main.c(357): mod_fcgid: gracefully terminated 1 processes
[Mon Apr 14 19:18:26 2014] [info] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(2628) exit(lifetime expired), terminated by calling exit(), return code: 0
[Mon Apr 14 19:18:56 2014] [debug] fcgid_pm_main.c(357): mod_fcgid: gracefully terminated 1 processes
[Mon Apr 14 19:19:02 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 2629 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Mon Apr 14 19:19:08 2014] [info] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(2629) exit(communication error), get stop signal 9
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the _right_ error_log?

Comment: No, I am not very good at server admin, but as it seems that the SIGKILL is related to the 500 error. Can you point me in a better direction?